# How can I add parameter to Filter stored procedure XML in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a stored procedure that send XML:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChartEnergyKPIS]
    @columns varchar(max),
    @groupBy varchar(max),
    @filters varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @query varchar(max)
    SET @query = 'declare @xml XML

    SET @xml = (SELECT '+ @columns + ' 
                FROM [dbo].[KPIS] k (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[KPISEnergy]  ke (NOLOCK) ON k.Id = ke.IdKPI
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Meter] m (NOLOCK) ON ke.IdMeter = m.Id
                ' + @filters + ' ' +
                @groupBy + ' FOR XML RAW) SELECT @xml';

    PRINT @query
    EXEC(@query)
END
```

That I want to do is filter this XML by `k.BranchOfficeId`, in C# class I call query something like:

```
public static string GetChartEnergy(string initDate, string endDate, string type)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var structure = new List<QueryStructure>();

    try
    {
        structure.Add(initDate.CreateQueryStructure(endDate, true, null, "convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103)", null, false));
        structure.Add(type.CreateQueryStructure(string.Empty, false, "CASE WHEN m.Type = 1 THEN 'Agua' ELSE CASE WHEN m.Type = 2 THEN 'Luz' ELSE 'Gas' END END AS Type", " m.type", "m.Type", false));

        //agrega una columna para sacar el total de registros por filtro
        structure.Add(new QueryStructure
                {
                    ColumnSelect = "SUM(ke.Month) AS Total",
                    Operator = Operator.Nothing,
                    ColumnWhere = string.Empty
                });

        result = Chars.GetChartInfo(structure, "ChartEnergyKPIS");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}
```

So my try to do it is simple to add filter into create query like and compare with currentUser I call in method:

```
public static string GetChartEnergy(string initDate, string endDate, string type, int currentUser)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var structure = new List<QueryStructure>();

    try
    {
        structure.Add(initDate.CreateQueryStructure(endDate, true, null, "convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103,k.BranchOfficeId = currentUser)", null, false));
```

and finally in a class I execute a stored procedure and get Json depending of applied filters:

```
public static string GetChartInfo(List<QueryStructure> queryStructure, string procedureName)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string xml = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var queryWhere = queryStructure.GetWhere();
        var columnsQuery = queryStructure.GetSelectGroupBy(true);
        var groupByQuery = queryStructure.GetSelectGroupBy(false);

        using (var oContext = new EF.SSMA())
        {
             SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@columns", columnsQuery);
             SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@groupBy", groupByQuery);
             SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@filters", queryWhere);

             xml = oContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("dbo.{0}  @columns, @groupBy, @filters", procedureName), param1, param2, param3).First();
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
         {
             XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
             doc.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", xml));
             doc.LoadXml("<root>" + xml + "</root>");

             result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
             result = result.Replace("{\"root\":{\"row\":", "");
             result = result.Replace("}}", "");
             result = result.Replace("\"@", "\"");

             if (result.Substring(0, 1) == "{")
             {
                 result = string.Format("[{0}]", result);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             result = "[]";
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }

     return result;
 }
```

Create query structure class:

```
   public static QueryStructure CreateQueryStructure(this String value, string endDate, bool isDate,
        string columnName, string whereName, string groupByName, bool isNullField)
    {
        QueryStructure structure = new QueryStructure();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            if (value != ",")
            {
                if (isDate)
                {
                    //obtiene la estructura para un filtro entre fechas
                    structure.ColumnSelect = columnName;
                    structure.ColumnGroupBy = groupByName;
                    structure.ColumnWhere = string.Format("({0} BETWEEN convert(datetime,\'{1}\', 103) and convert(datetime,\'{2}\', 103))", whereName, value.Remove(value.Length - 1), endDate.Remove(value.Length - 1));
                    structure.Values = null;
                    structure.Operator = Operator.Nothing;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (isNullField)
                    {
                        //obtiene la estructura de un filtro por un campo que es null o no
                        if (value.Remove(value.Length - 1) != "-1")
                        {
                            structure.ColumnWhere = string.Format("{0} IS{1} NULL", whereName,
                                value.Remove(value.Length - 1) == "0"
                                                                    ? " NOT" :
                                                                    string.Empty);

                            structure.Values = null;
                            structure.Operator = Operator.And;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //obtiene la estructura de un campo aplicando la regla IN seleccionando
                        //el campo a mostrar y el campo en groupBy
                        structure.ColumnSelect = columnName;
                        structure.ColumnGroupBy = groupByName;
                        structure.ColumnWhere = whereName;
                        structure.Values = value.Remove(value.Length - 1);
                        structure.Operator = Operator.And;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return structure;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, How can I add parameter to Filter stored procedure XML in C#? @RobertHarvey

Comment: SQL Server has mechanisms that allow you to query on XML elements.  Is that what you are looking for?  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/

Comment: Originally  received xml correctly with correctly filters (I don´t do this code), but I need to update it. I just want to filter it by one more field but I don´t understand much how it works @RobertHarvey

Comment: It would appear that you need to modify your `ColumnWhere` in the `QueryStructure` to provide the correct filter.

Comment: Yes, and I try to do that in CreateQueryStructure adding line  `k.BranchOfficeId = currentUser` like in my post but it isn´t works I get incorrect syntax near ´,´ @RobertHarvey

Comment: Without my try into GetChartinfo method (last one) I received in `queryWhere` this: `"WHERE (convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01/02/2014', 103) and convert(datetime,'31/10/2016', 103)) And  m.type IN (1) "` @RobertHarvey

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code you've provided where that clause would be created.  Find the place where these `WHERE` and `AND` clauses are being specified.

Comment: Alright, I post in my  question @RobertHarvey

Comment: Be very careful using NOLOCK. It is far more sinister than most people realize. If you want accurate results in your query you absolutely MUST not use that hint. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows along with a handful of other things that will drive you crazy. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: are you there? @RobertHarvey :(

Comment: Hi Dawin! As you are quite new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your error happens here:

```
structure.Add(initDate.CreateQueryStructure(endDate, true, null, "convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103,k.BranchOfficeId = currentUser)", null, false)
```

or, more in detail, here:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103,k.BranchOfficeId = currentUser)
```

What you are doing is, to add your `k.BranchOfficeId = currentUser` as a fourth parameter to the `CONVERT`-function. This is a sure *syntax error near ','*.

If this additional condition is something you want to **add in any case** it would be easiest to add this in the place where you set your `ColumnWhere` in this way:

```
k.BranchOfficeId = currentUser AND (The other condition you use normally)
```

But here is your next issue: It looks like `currentUser` is a variable in your application. You must use the value, rather than the name

Something like

```
string.Format(" k.BranchOfficeId = {0} AND ({1}) ",currentUser,TheConditionAsItWasBefore)
```

Hope this helps...

And to be honest: This looks far to complicated, prone to SQL injection and you might show this to the folks on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)