# Add filter using XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have method and Query like this:

```
public static string GetChartEnergy(string initDate, string endDate, string type)
        {
structure.Add(initDate.CreateQueryStructure(endDate, true, null, "convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103)", null, false));
structure.Add(type.CreateQueryStructure(string.Empty, false, "CASE WHEN m.Type = 1 THEN 'Agua' ELSE CASE WHEN m.Type = 2 THEN 'Luz' ELSE 'Gas' END END AS Type", " m.type", "m.Type", false));
        }
```

CreateQueryStructure is this one:

```
   public static QueryStructure CreateQueryStructure(this String value, string endDate, bool isDate,
            string columnName, string whereName, string groupByName, bool isNullField)
        {
            QueryStructure structure = new QueryStructure();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if (value != ",")
                {
                    if (isDate)
                    {
                        //obtiene la estructura para un filtro entre fechas
                        structure.ColumnSelect = columnName;
                        structure.ColumnGroupBy = groupByName;
                        structure.ColumnWhere = string.Format("({0} BETWEEN convert(datetime,\'{1}\', 103) and convert(datetime,\'{2}\', 103))", whereName, value.Remove(value.Length - 1), endDate.Remove(value.Length - 1));
                        structure.Values = null;
                        structure.Operator = Operator.Nothing;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (isNullField)
                        {
                            //obtiene la estructura de un filtro por un campo que es null o no
                            if (value.Remove(value.Length - 1) != "-1")
                            {
                                structure.ColumnWhere = string.Format("{0} IS{1} NULL", whereName,
                                    value.Remove(value.Length - 1) == "0"
                                                                        ? " NOT" :
                                                                        string.Empty);

                                structure.Values = null;
                                structure.Operator = Operator.And;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //obtiene la estructura de un campo aplicando la regla IN seleccionando
                            //el campo a mostrar y el campo en groupBy
                            structure.ColumnSelect = columnName;
                            structure.ColumnGroupBy = groupByName;
                            structure.ColumnWhere = whereName;
                            structure.Values = value.Remove(value.Length - 1);
                            structure.Operator = Operator.And;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return structure;
        }
```

OUTPUT: `"(convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01/01/2014', 103) and convert(datetime,'31/10/2016', 103))"`

Now when it pass from two `CreateQueryStructure` I have another method like:

```
public static string GetChartInfo(List<QueryStructure> queryStructure, string procedureName)
        {
                var queryWhere = queryStructure.GetWhere();
}
```

So now it pass to `GetWhere`:

```
  public static string GetWhere(this List<QueryStructure> filters)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0)
            {
                if (filters.Select(x => x.ColumnWhere).Any())
                {
                    result += "WHERE ";

                    foreach (var filter in filters)
                    {
                        if (filter.Operator != Operator.Nothing)
                        {
                            result += " " + filter.Operator.ToString() + " ";
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Values))
                        {
                            result += filter.ColumnWhere + " IN (";

                            result += filter.Values;

                            result += ") ";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result += filter.ColumnWhere;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

And finally it return Output with where clause:

```
"WHERE (convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01/01/2014', 103) and convert(datetime,'31/10/2016', 103)) And  m.type IN (2) "
```

And I want to change where clause to get only items of currentUser, so I get currentUser in method sending parameter from controller like:

```
public static string GetChartEnergy(string initDate, string endDate, string type, int currentUser) //there I have currentUser
```

Now, how can I add this filter to:

```
structure.Add(initDate.CreateQueryStructure(endDate, true, null, "convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103)", null, false));
```

in linq I just need to do some like `x => x.user == currentUser` but in xml I don´t know how, can any one help me?. Regards

Update: Query Structure class:

```
public class QueryStructure
    {
        public string ColumnGroupBy { get; set; }

        public string ColumnSelect { get; set; }

        public string ColumnWhere { get; set; }
        public Operator Operator { get; set; }

        public string Values { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Can  you please elaborate what is your input vs output of the above function also it will be good if you paste QueryStructure class.

Comment: I restructurate my question to be more clear @DirtyDeveloper

Comment: can you please paste the QueryStructure model class as well

Comment: There is @DirtyDeveloper

Comment: are you there? @DirtyDeveloper

Comment: yes, can you please provide which params you are passing to GEtChartEnergy(x,y,z) methods?

Comment: Yes. `initDate = 01/02/2015`,  `endDate = 01/10/2016`, `type = 1` and `whereName` in CreateQueryStructure is `"convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103)"` @DirtyDeveloper

Comment: @Dawin, which RDBMS is this running against? I assume it's SQL-Server... Correct? Which version?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 @Shnugo

Comment: @Dawin Before I start to write a new answer: Did you check the answer I posted shortly at [your previous, very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40348135/5089204)?

Comment: Yes I check it, but I try @DirtyDeveloper answer and it works, I just make some changes to it

Comment: @Dawin , if it has worked for you, you can upvote my answer below as well as mark it as an answer which will help other guys to recognize the correct response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your methods it will be very simpler:

```
public static string GetChartEnergy(string initDate, string endDate, string type,string currentUser)
    {
structure.Add(initDate.CreateQueryStructure(endDate, true, null, "convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103)", null, false));
structure.Add(type.CreateQueryStructure(string.Empty, false, "CASE WHEN m.Type = 1 THEN 'Agua' ELSE CASE WHEN m.Type = 2 THEN 'Luz' ELSE 'Gas' END END AS Type", " m.type", "m.Type", false));

structure.Add(curentUser.CreateQueryStructure(string.Empty, false, string.Empty, "m.User", string.Empty, false));
}
```

assuming **m.User** is the user column to filter
which will give you output like this

```
WHERE (convert(datetime,'15/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Month) + '/' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), k.Year), 103) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01/01/2014', 103) and convert(datetime,'31/10/2016', 103)) And  m.type IN (2) AND m.User IN("yourusername")
```

Comment: @Dawin, let me know once you run against this your code and let me know if you require modifications

Comment: Of course, I test it tomorrow and I advice you if it works. Thank you alot ! Regards

Comment: Dirty are you there?

Comment: Yes it worked, I edit your answer with correct solution

Comment: @Dawin, I have updated the answer. may be new answer works for you

Comment: Thank you so much!, there is answer. Regards